# How to read reliably CTS and DSR status of a Serial Port with C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, i2c

Back in time(15 years ago) i made a small program on Delphi to monitor, record and show a time-diagram the signals from a I2C communication between PC and I2C-sensor. Now i need the same thing and i have big problem to adapt it for C#. In general i connect CTS line from the serial port to SCL line of a I2C, and DSR to SDA. Then i start a thread that read the status of the CTS and DSR(with endless loop) and save them to a file. This is the code:

```
        void InitCommPort()
        {
            myCOMport = new SerialPort("COM2", 9600);
            myCOMport.Open();
        }

        while (!bExit)
        {
            CTS_Signal = myCOMport.CtsHolding;
            DSR_Signal = myCOMport.DsrHolding;
        }
```

The problem is that i can not get the signals[CTS and DSR] fast enough to reconstruct the communication protocol. Actually mostly i can get only one of the signals, and it is just part of the all transfer. I tried also "SerialPinChangedEventHandler", but I'm receiving only '0' as a result. Obviously I'm missing something or just the SerialPort-Class is made in this way. Is it possible to be done with C#? I do not want to install Windows XP for something simple like that. Any help will be appreciated.
Thank You in advance

Comment: So, use FreePascal to compile your nice program. https://www.freepascal.org/

Comment: Using handshaking either hardware of software is archaic.  There should be no reason these days to write code like you are doing.  The handshaking was designed when BAUD rates were 50 bits a second and does not work well with today's standard using 9600 bits a second or higher.

Comment: So what wold be the NON-archaic solution to read these inputs to the PC? Thank You!

Comment: @jdweng *"Using handshaking either hardware of software is archaic"* -- According to whom?  If the receiving device cannot process the data fast enough and is running out of buffer/memory, then why shouldn't it use flow control?  A fast baudrate doesn't obsolete flow control.  It means that the device has to be more tolerant of a delayed response.

Comment: Tell me any situation today where  a receiving device is too slow the receive data.  You can always go to a slower baud rate.  A serial channel should be using a Master/Slave configuration where the client send data and waits for the server to respond.  Any other configuration is just a bad design and you are using obsolete method as a kludge to fix a poor design.

Comment: @jdweng, you are so, so wrong. Hardware handshake is not used you will get data loss. Any non-RT OS will give you such a bad behaviour.

Comment: I can teach the course in College. Just throwing commands at an Operating System is just poor design relying on the hardware control lines.  Command should be ack by server which will throttle the input instead of using handshaking which the world stopped using 40 years ago (except you).   Most cables you buy off the shelf doesn't have the hardware control wires so the code will not work.  Most devices do not implement the handshaking any more.

Comment: After 1 day reading documents and examples i reached conclusion that i have to get control of the Serial-port on low level to accomplish this task, in another words i have to make DRIVER for the Seial-Port-too much work..i am lazy. So yesterday night i found one of my Arduino nano, FTDI232[USB to RS232]converter from the drawer and a SD-Card reader, and after 2 hours i had working project. I received a beautiful time diagram of the I2C protocol. It is better thаn i expected- a bit more wires but the most important: it did the job.

Comment: @jdweng, go ahead. Had you chance to read this: https://lore.kernel.org/linux-serial/20200407091611.GA657631@kroah.com/T/#t ?